# Get sessionStorage key value from browser

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I had used Webdriver Sampler to login in my web application as my application logged in using google signin .

Another related request is required an auth_token , which is stored in sessionStorage of browser ,

How can I get it?

I try this but gives me an error

WebDriverSampler: TypeError: WDS.browser.sessionStorage is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`WDS.Browser.executeScript()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method and call [window.sessionStorage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) function like:

```
var foo = WDS.browser.executeScript("return window.sessionStorage.getItem('foo');")
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter WebDriver Get Value from session storage]

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered)

Comment: Thanks , I am able to get JSon body , how can i extarct value from key 'auth_toke'. ?

Comment: I have no idea unless I see the body, most probably you can go for `JSON.parse()`: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Comment: Thanks , I figure that out : var obj = JSON.parse(foo);
        WDS.log.info(obj.oauth_token)